# Up/down voting script

Tags: php, mysql, rating, voting

I'm trying to develop a voting system in PHP for my posts where visitors can vote them up or down and then I should be able to sort posts by highest/lowest rated.

Can anyone please recommend a good script I can use for this?

Comment: Just write one yourself.. It's not as if there are script for any custom system anyway...

Comment: Look son, pedantic comments, pedantic comments everywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following links refer you to pages with a bunch of such voting scripts. Some are free and some you have to pay for:

- [Voting scripts for PHP at
  hotscripts.com](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/polls-voting/)
- [Voting scripts
  for PHP at scripts.com](http://www.scripts.com/php-scripts/poll-and-voting-scripts/)
- [Voting scripts for PHP at best-php-scripts.com](http://best-php-scripts.com/voting_scripts.htm)
- [Voting scripts for PHP at resourceindex.com](http://php.resourceindex.com/Complete_Scripts/Survey_and_Voting/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no "script" that will magically do this for you.

You will need to create a table in your MySQL database, which at the very least has two fields, post id, and vote count.

You will also need to create a PHP page which handles vote updates as well as returning posts in sorted order.

Comment: -1 You're wrong. It depends what we're talking about. There are external services for that matter, or even scripts that "attach" to the current system called module in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one: http://www.technabled.com/2011/02/pulse-lite-reddit-ajax-up-down-voting.html
Disclosure: I am the developer.

Comment: It says "Redirecting to advertiser" when I click "DEMO". If you fix that I'll upvote your answer

Comment: Sorry, Dad. That domain has been out-of-order for ages.